# Static field works, dynamically modified element gets lost

Tags: 7, forms

I'm new to Drupal forms - trying to figure out a maddening problem.

I have a content type of 'doc-upload' with various fields including 'publisher_code'.

When I define the 'publisher_code' field type to 'text', and go through my upload process, yada yada yada, the value appears in my $node structure later as expected.

When I change 'publisher_code' to "field type: List (text), widget: Select list", and I try to dynamically populate that element with:

```
function mymodule_form_doc_upload_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $publishers = array( 'pub1' => 'Publisher 1', 'pub2' => 'Publisher 2' );

  $form['field_publisher_code'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Select a publisher'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $publishers,
    '#multiple' => FALSE,
    '#empty_value' => '',
    '#empty_option' => '- None -',
    '#required' => TRUE
  );
}
```

The form displays properly, but when the form is submitted, the 'field_publisher_code' doesn't come out the other side - presumably it's getting filtered/invalidated somewhere, but I can't seem to find where?

Comment: what is the type of the Publisher_code? and is there some reason you dont want use the select list already available in the content type field?

Comment: When I define 'publisher_code' as a regular text field, and enter a value on the 'create new doc-upload content type', it appears in the $node object after all the processing.

Comment: why dont you add the field to the content type rather than doing this.

Comment: The field 'publisher_code' *IS* added to content-type 'doc-upload'. I need to dynamically build the list of publishers (which is another content-type). My example is limited in scope to illustrate the true nature of the problem - if 'publisher_code' is a regular text field and NOT modified in the form_alter() function above, it works fine. When I try to change the field type to 'Select' and modify it in the function, it doesn't. I don't know if it's because of the field Select type, or that I'm changing the field incorrectly.

Comment: Do you want to list all the nodes in the other content type or a sub set of that? If you want to list all then you can add an entity reference field and then use it instead.

Comment: I just need a list of another content-type 'publishers'. I will look into 'entity reference field' as well, but I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong on this particular problem so I can feel confident dealing with forms going forward. I feel like I'm so close and it's something really stupid - just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

instead of over writing the form element just edit variables you want to change something like below

```
  $publishers = array( 'pub1' => 'Publisher 1', 'pub2' => 'Publisher 2' );

  $form['field_publisher_code']['#type'] = 'select';
  $form['field_publisher_code']['#options'] = $publishers;
  $form['field_publisher_code']['#multiple'] = FALSE;
```

I presume your $form already has the variable when you get the form.

Comment: Bingo - this is the answer I was looking for.. thank you!